# Json displaying blank

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, django, web

I'm making a request from a json file in a webpage, but is returning a blank screen.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';


function App() {

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get("https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/last/USD-BRL")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("ok")
        console.log(response.data)
        setPosts(response.data)
      }).catch(() => {
        console.log("erro")
      })
    
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {posts?.map((post, key) =>{
      return(  
      <div key={key}>
        <td></td>
        <td>Dolar</td>
        <td>{post.bid}</td>
        <td>{post.create_date}</td>
      </div>)
    })}

  );
}

export default App;
```

The console is able to see the json file, but the page on the browser is completely blank:

[image]

I tried many json files, and only one worked out, was this one: https://api.covid19api.com/countries

I had this same problem using React and Django.

Comment: Can you post how `setPosts` is defined, because that's not visible in your code? Also, if you inspect the rendered page, can you see your `div` and `td`s? As a sidenote - your table is missing the rest of its tags.

Comment: @FiddlingAway How should i define 'SetPosts'? Because there is no other reference about it in the project.

And also the div's and td's are not visible at the inspect page

Comment: Can you try to look at the console and what kind of error you are getting or only blank page without any error ?

Comment: @Hrusikesh
https://i.imgur.com/zNVr2pY.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to map like below for the keys of an object

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/last/USD-BRL")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("ok");
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log(response.data.USDBRL);
        console.log(response.data.USDBRL.bid);
        console.log(response.data.USDBRL.create_date);
        setPosts(response.data.USDBRL);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("erro");
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {Object.keys(posts).map((keyName, i) => {
    if (keyName === "bid") {
      return (
        <li className="travelcompany-input" key={i}>
          <span className="input-label">
            Bid: {posts["bid"]}
            Create Date: {posts["create_date"]}
          </span>
        </li>
      );
    }
  })}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and the result is like below

[image]